# How to use wireless projectors on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, windows, display, alternative, projector

We use wireless projectors in my school and the Windows users can connect easily using the "EZ Display" application. Is there an application for Ubuntu that i can use to project my display wirelessly or is there another solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found something that might work. You could try Mirrorop which can run as an extension under chrome or chromium. I need to test it still personally

Comment: never work. i tried out. still find way to overcome my office issue.